# Google speech API error[32] broken pipe when using own API key

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I tried using google speech API for converting my audio speech input to text with raspberry pi 0 and python code. I added my billing account and enabled the GOOGLE SPEECH API service in Google console.I generated my own API key for google speech API and tried using it in python script but when I run the script I get error[32] broken pipe,connection failed.Please may I know the reason for not being able to access the API key.Does google speech API require any authentication process or any problem with the code.My python code is below

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
     print("Say something!")
     audio = r.listen(source)
try:
     print (r.recognize_google(audio, key="my_api_key"))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
     print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
     print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))
```

Error is:

```
say something!
could not request results from google speech recognition services
recognition connection failed:[ERROR 32] broken pipe
```

Comment: I've been trying to reproduce your issue but have been getting errors in earlier steps. If you intend to use google's speech-to-text api, is there any particular reason why you are not using the official python [cloud client library](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize#performing_streaming_speech_recognition_on_an_audio_stream)?

Comment: I tried using it but i was unable to install google cloud SDK.

Comment: What issues did you encounter with installing the SDK? Can you provide details/error messages? I know this is a diversion from your actual question, but using the cloud client is the suggested approach so it might be worth it.

Comment: I am using Raspbian jessie.To set up glcoud i followed the steps using client library.I set up the path of JSON file for LINUX.Then downloaded the google-cloud-sdk package for 32bit Linux and tried installing using the shell command ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh.While doing so i got the error as:                                                    bash:./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh:permission denied.                                                 I also have a doubt if whether i might have gone wrong proceeding with linux steps instead of using debian/ubuntu steps,as iam using raspbian jessie.

Comment: 1) I was wrong in saying that the cloud client is the suggested approach, in fact, it's still in alpha and is **not** recommended for production. Still, I am not convinced that SpeechRecognition is a better solution. 2) It might sound redundant but 'permission denied' is usually symptomatic of not using sudo. 3) You should indeed use the debian steps.

Comment: 4) On your original question: how did you install pyaudio? `pip3 install pyaudio` does not work for me. When I do `sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio python3-pyaudio`, the lib is installed but, then, when running your code, I get an `AttributeError: module 'pyaudio' has no attribute '__version__'` error message.

Comment: Even i faced that problem while working but then resolved it by following steps,1)sudo apt-get remove python-pyaudio python3-pyaudio 2)sudo -H pip install pyaudio==0.2.11 --upgrade .Try doing this.